# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou recebendo o erro abaixo, entendi que o programa tenta acessar uma posição inexistente, porém não consigo corrigir...O código é um trabalho que tenho que completar e incrementar:

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 12 cObject.computeMapping("corpus.txt")
> 13 # Chamada do algoritmo genetico
> ---> 14 listLog = geneticAlgorithm(cObject, message)
>
> in geneticAlgorithm(cypherObject,
> mensagemCodificada, tamanhoPopulacao, numeroGeracoes, nMelhores)
> 26       # Fitness pode ser uma lista que armazena os valores de probabilidade
> 27       print("I antes do fitness:", i, "J antes do fitness:", j)
> ---> 28       fitness, mensagemTraduzida = cypherObject.computeLogProbability(mensagemCodificada, populacao[j])
> 29       print("I depois do fitness:", i, "I depois do fitness:", j, "\n")
> 30
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

O trecho do código com o problema:

```
def geneticAlgorithm(cypherObject, mensagemCodificada, tamanhoPopulacao=10, numeroGeracoes=10, nMelhores=10):
  
  # Observacoes
  #   Guardar a melhor probabilidade (criar variavel)
  #   Criar uma variavel para armazenar a melhor traducao

  # Gerar uma populacao inicial
  populacao = []
  newPopulacao = []
  fitness = []
  listaLogProbabilidade = []
  melhorTraducao = []

  listaFitness = []
  for i in range(tamanhoPopulacao):
    listaCaracteres = list(cypherObject.getAlphabet())
    random.shuffle(listaCaracteres)
    resultado = "".join(listaCaracteres)
    populacao.append(resultado)
    print("\n", populacao) # teste para validar se a população está sendo gerada corretamente.
  
  for i in range(numeroGeracoes):
    # Calcular o fitness da populacao
    #print("Teste de for do i:", i)
    for j in range(tamanhoPopulacao):
      # Fitness pode ser uma lista que armazena os valores de probabilidade
      print("I antes do fitness:", i, "J antes do fitness:", j)
      fitness, mensagemTraduzida = cypherObject.computeLogProbability(mensagemCodificada, populacao[j])
      print("I depois do fitness:", i, "I depois do fitness:", j, "\n")
    

    # Selecionar os melhores valores de fitness (Posso ordenar os valores de fitness)
    # https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html
    # Ordenar valores e retornar os indices dos valores
    listaFitnessIndices =  np.argsort(listaFitness)[::-1]

    # Aplicar alteracoes na populacao
    #   Selecionar os N melhores
    #   Adicionar cromossomos mutados
    #   Cruzamento dos N melhores (Implementar depois) 
    #   populacao[algum indice] = ['axcke'] (Mutacao do cromossomo)
    #       Sugestao: Trocar posicoes do vetor de lugar
    #         Ajudou a cair menos em maximos locais
    #   Gerar novos cromossomos de forma aleatoria (primeiro trecho do codigo)

    populacao = newPopulacao.copy()

  return listaLogProbabilidade, melhorTraducao
```

Answer (score 0):

Você instanciou a lista aqui:

```
listaFitness = []
for i in range(tamanhoPopulacao):
```

Depois usou ela aqui:

```
listaFitnessIndices =  np.argsort(listaFitness)[::-1]
```

Mas neste meio caminho entre instanciar ela e usar você não a preencheu, acho que deve ter esquecido algum código, se no seu código for possível que em alguma situação a lista não seja preenchida não pode esquecer de verificar se a variável está preenchida com alguma coisa antes de usar ela.